# Repeat a string n times in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm looking for a concise way to repeat a string of characters *n* times, where *n* is a variable. I couldn't find good wat to do that in the [docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply use [`list`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html) to iterate a [range](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_ranges):

```
<#assign n = 5>
<#list 0..<n as i>hello</#list>
```

Or as a macro:

```
<#macro repeat input times>
<#list 0..<times as i>${input}</#list>
</#macro>

<@repeat input="hello" times=5/>
```

Comment: You should use, `0..<times`, as `1..times` will go backwards from 1 if `n` is `0`.

Comment: Modified! Thanks for putting that out.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to repeat a single character `c` for `n` times, you could do `${''?left_pad(n, c)}`. It's a bit critic though, so perhaps you want to put it into a `#function` with proper name.