# How to use Loops in FTL and print something n times

Tags: freemarker

hey there I want to use loop in ftl and and print the html n time inside loop

for(int i=0; i<=3;i++){
print(html)
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat a string n times in freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264184/repeat-a-string-n-times-in-freemarker)

Answer (score 0):

```
<#list 1..10 as i>
${html}
</#list>
```

Replace 10 with n / the desired number of iterations.